# XSLT variable print as an attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there's a way to print the variable in the element as an attribute?

sample xml:

```
<list>
<name>John Doe</name>
<name>Paul Niel</name>
<name>Luke Dee</name>
</list>
```

Here's my sample xslt;

```
<xsl:variable name="isDisabled">
    <xsl:if test="name='John Doe'">
        <xsl:attribute name="disabled">disabled</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

and I want to print the isDisabled varible like this;

```
<input id="textName" name="name" type="text" {$isDisabled} />
```

output;

```
<input id="textName" name="name" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: So, what is the source XML document and what is the wanted result of the transformation. Any rules for transforming the former into the latter? Please, edit the question and provide this important information.

Comment: mrrsb: You don't really need a variable in order to accomplish this task -- see my answer for details.

Comment: mrrsb: See also the very end of the answer (just added), which targets your question directly.

Comment: Please note, XSLT doesn't "print" anything. It doesn't even output a string. It creates a tree of nodes. This might seem pernickety, just as it was pernickety to correct the spelling of "XSLT" in your title, but precision in thought and writing is what distinguishes a good programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need any variable to accomplish this task**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="name[. = 'John Doe']">
  <input id="textName" name="name" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<list>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <name>Paul Niel</name>
    <name>Luke Dee</name>
</list>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<input id="textName" name="name" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of templates and template pattern matching.

**Note**: If you have a case (not this one) where it is *really* necessary to use a variable to create an attribute, this can be done in the following way:

```
<input id="textName" name="name" type="text" disabled="{$isDisabled}"/>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of AVT (**[Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**)

Comment: I stumbled a couple of times over this answer via web search, and I was only looking for the syntax `some-attribute={$some-variable}` (I always forget it). Maybe it should be on top of this answer because it answers the actual question. The rest is very specific to @mrrsb's case.